# Simple Error Handling for GoTo or Other

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to create a macro that will allow a User to click a button and the excel sheet will either 1: Move to the next/previous sheet or 2: Copy existing sheet and then move to the copied sheet.

Currently I'm stuck dealing w/ a error handling situation and am not sure how to get around it. I'm not sure if I'm using the On Error correctly. Essentially I need it to go to my next sub if a page doesn't exist. If the page does exist, to simply ActiveSheet.Index + 1 then select.

```
Sub Function1()
     On Error GoTo fixer
     Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Select
fixer:
     Call Copier2
End Sub

Sub Copier2()
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy _
       After:=ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm quite a novice at this stuff so don't be afraid to dumb it down for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807347/how-do-i-use-on-error-goto

Comment: What is currently happening if the page doesn't exist?

Comment: And you don't need the Call key word.

Comment: And you want an Exit Sub after the first .Select or else you will continue onto fixer even if there is no error.

Comment: FWIW `Function[Whatever]` is a very very bad name for a `Sub` procedure. A "Function" is a procedure *that returns a value*. If the macro means to navigate to the next sheet, name it `NavigateToNextSheet` or something, and then thank yourself later.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for the tip. I simply used it as a filler for the moment. It's not going to be a long drawn out script so in the end it likely won't matter much. I realized it when I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have some fun with this, to illustrate the mechanics.

First let's *extract a method* whose job is to activate a given worksheet. That method will return a `Boolean` value that indicates whether it succeeded or not. Because we want to *return a value*, this will be a `Function` procedure:

```
Private Function ActivateSheet(ByVal index As Long) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(index).Select
    result = True
CleanExit:
    ActivateSheet = result
    Exit Function
CleanFail:
    Err.Clear
    result = False
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
```

The "happy path" assigns `result` to `True` and then assigns the function's return value to `result` and then returns.

The "error path" jumps to `CleanFail`, which clears the error (likely some *index out of bounds* error), assigns `result` to `False` and then `Resume CleanExit` clears the error-handling state and *resumes* to `CleanExit`, which assigns the function's return value to `result` and then returns.

The macro can do this now:

```
Public Sub NavigateRight()
    If Not ActivateSheet(ActiveSheet.Index + 1) Then
    'copy the current sheet if there's no next sheet:
        ActiveSheet.Copy After:=ActiveSheet
    End If
End Sub
```

And we can also have this one:

```
Public Sub NavigateLeft()
    If Not ActivateSheet(ActiveSheet.Index - 1) Then
    'copy the current sheet if there's no previous sheet:
        ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=ActiveSheet
    End If
End Sub
```

Don't make procedures just for the sake of making procedures: use them to *abstract concepts*: a procedure like `Copier2` doesn't really need to exist, it's just wrapping a single call against the Excel object model - better to inline it IMO.

Comment: WOW! That makes a ton of sense. I didn't think of approaching it from this point. This is going to make things a ton easier. That's a very clever loop of sorts to handle the error.